# How to destroy sprite objects in Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, flame

Does removeFromParent destroys object? I mean Garbage collects it, I am looking for destroy method but couldn't find.

update:

```
import 'package:flame/components.dart';

class Enemy extends SpriteAnimationComponent with HasGameRef {
  @override
  Future<void>? onLoad() async {
    position = Vector2(200, 100);
    size = Vector2(100, 100);

    var spriteAnimationData = SpriteAnimationData.sequenced(
      amount: 12,
      stepTime: 0.05,
      textureSize: Vector2(30, 30),
    );

    animation =
        await gameRef.loadSpriteAnimation('enemy/pig.png', spriteAnimationData);
    anchor = Anchor.center;

    return super.onLoad();
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    position += Vector2(-2, 0);

    if (position.x < -20) {
      removeFromParent();
    }  

    super.update(dt);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Dart is a garbage collected language it will garbage collect unused objects automatically once there are no references to the object anymore.

However, `Sprite`s are a bit special since they have a loaded image in them. In Flame `1.0.0` the image cache (or the sprite class) does not call `dispose` of these images when it is cleared (but on `main`, and in the next version this will be done).

So to properly free up memory you'll have to call `image.dispose()` after you have removed the `SpriteComponent`, you could do `sprite.image.dispose()` in `onRemove` of the `SpriteComponent` for example, or call `spriteComponent.sprite.image.dispose()` after it has been removed.

EDIT: Since the question is now updated.

To call dispose on all `Image`s loaded into a `SpriteAnimationComponent` you would have to do something like this:

```dart
component.animation.frames.forEach((f) => f.sprite.image.dispose());
```

Since those images are also loaded into the image cache they will also be removed when you remove an entry (or clear the whole cache) in the next version.

Reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Image/dispose.html

Comment: For being garbage collected automatically I've to remove any reference to the corresponding object, so I call  `removeFromParent()` inside update method of enemy class if enemy is out of sight and it removes the objects, but does `removeFromParent()`  removes all references to the object? How to see a list of added objects to the game to be sure removed object is deleted? I couldn't find the dispose method of `SpriteAnimationComponent`.

Comment: Flame removes all internal references to it after it has been removed, so If you don't keep any references to the object yourself lying around it will get garbage collected. For `SpriteAnimationComponent` it is quite cumbersome to call `dispose` for all images in there (but this is also solved in the next version), you would have to call `component.animation.frames.forEach((f) => f.sprite.image.dispose());`